# Как сверстать этот блок?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, css-animation

*текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите как сверстать такой блок  без анимации на CSS?

Comment: чаще всего нужно бывает динамически изменять бар. для "вашего же блага" рекомендую использовать какую нибудь библиотеку к примеру https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно еще проще.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
li { list-style-type: none; }
p { margin: .5rem 0 2.5rem .5rem;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase; }

progress, output { display: block; }
progress { border-radius: 0; width: 100%; height: 5px; }
progress::-webkit-progress-bar { background-color: #aaa; }
progress::-moz-progress-bar { background-color: #aaa; }
progress::-webkit-progress-value { background-color: #000; }
progress::-moz-progress-value { background-color: #000; }

li output { position: absolute; transform: translate(-4rem, .5rem); }
li:nth-child(1) output{ margin-left: 90%; }
li:nth-child(2) output{ margin-left: 80%; }
li:nth-child(3) output{ margin-left: 85%; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <progress value="0.90"></progress>
    <output>90%</output>
    <p>Branding</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <progress value=".80"></progress>
    <output>80%</output>
    <p>Design</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <progress value=".85"></progress>
    <output>85%</output>
    <p>Development</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: цифорок нету, как в примере

Comment: @МихаилКамахин уже есть

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

```css
.progress {
    position:     relative;
    
    border-top:   3px solid black;
    
    width:        300px;
    
    padding-top:  10px;
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

.progress:after {
    position:     absolute;
    top:          -3px;
    right:        0px;
    
    border-top:   3px solid #c0c0c0;

    width:        calc(100% - 75%);
    
    padding-top:  10px;
    margin-left: -24px;

    content:      "75%";

    text-indent:  -25%;
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    
    color:        #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'progress'>НАЗВАНИЕ</div>
```